# Conditionally render Menu Items in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and using below code to dynamically render Menu Items based on boolean variables, but its not working.

1. I want to disable 1st menu Item based on isSSProfile Flag.
2. Want to hide/show 2nd menu item based on other isSuperuser flag.

In stateless compenent

```
export default function MenuAppBar(props) {

  const [isSuperuser, setisSuperuser] = useState(props.isSuperuser);
  const [isSSProfile, setisSSProfile] = useState(props.isValidProfile);
```

```
  {!isSSProfile &&(
  <MenuItem component={Link} to="/Profile"  onClick={handleProfile} disabled> 
  Profile
  </MenuItem>
  )}

  {isSSProfile &&(
 <MenuItem component={Link} to="/Profile"  onClick={handleProfile}> 
 Profile
 </MenuItem>
 )}

 {isSuperuser &&(
 <MenuItem component={Link} to="/users"  onClick={handleUesrs}> 
 Users
 </MenuItem>
 )}
```

Please suggest suitable approach for the same..

Comment: Please provide more code area. Where declared isssprofile property? What is default value?

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: Where are `setisSuperuser` and `setisSSProfile` being called? When you say it's "not working", what specifically is not happening that you expect to happen?

Comment: disable/enable is working correctly w.r.t 1st flag. 
but hiding of 2nd menu item is not working when 1st menu item is disabled...only this condition is failing. I am not setting state..does it required if I am only accessing props value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue in my code, its about boolean true/false value are not setting up correctly.

At one place I was getting **isSuperuser** value from database and it was getting string values 'true'/'false'.
Also, I realized that I can use variables instead of State in my code:

```
const isSSuser = props.isValidSSUser
const isSuperuser = props.isSuperuser
```

Answer (score 1):

The rendering logic looks correct, though the `return` statement of the functional component is missing.

Also, the rendering of the first menu item can be simplified by disabling it conditionly like `disabled={!isSSProfile}`:

```
export default function MenuAppBar(props) {
  const [isSuperuser, setisSuperuser] = useState(props.isSuperuser);
  const [isSSProfile, setisSSProfile] = useState(props.isValidProfile);

  return (
    <>
      <MenuItem
        component={Link}
        to="/Profile"
        onClick={handleProfile}
        disabled={!isSSProfile}
      >
        Profile
      </MenuItem>

      {isSuperuser && (
        <MenuItem component={Link} to="/users" onClick={handleUesrs}>
          Users
        </MenuItem>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```